# Magento 2 Override Block is not returning to parent

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks, overrides

I have override magento core block `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs` to programatically add Breadcrumbs on product page due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576614/programmatically-add-breadcrumbs-paths-in-magento) issue

So I have created below code to solve this issue.
It is working correct in Core file also it is generating correct output in override file. But it is not retruning any value to core file as `return parent::_toHtml();` not working.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MyModule\Customization\Block\Product;

/**
 * Html page breadcrumbs block
 */
class Breadcrumbs extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs 
{
    protected $_template = 'html/breadcrumbs.phtml';
    protected $_properties = ['label', 'title', 'link', 'first', 'last', 'readonly'];
    protected $_crumbs;
    protected $_cacheKeyInfo;

    public function addCrumb($crumbName, $crumbInfo)
    {
        foreach ($this->_properties as $key) {
            if (!isset($crumbInfo[$key])) {
                $crumbInfo[$key] = null;
            }
        }

        if (!isset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName]) || !$this->_crumbs[$crumbName]['readonly']) {
            $this->_crumbs[$crumbName] = $crumbInfo;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        if ($this->_cacheKeyInfo === null) {
            $this->_cacheKeyInfo = parent::getCacheKeyInfo() + [
            'crumbs' => base64_encode(serialize($this->_crumbs)),
            'name' => $this->getNameInLayout(),
            ];
        }
        return $this->_cacheKeyInfo;
    }

    protected function _toHtml() {
        $cat_id = "";
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

        if ($objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product')) {
          $product_id = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product')->getEntityid();
          $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

          if ($product_id) {
             $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
             $cat_id = $categoryIds[0];
          }

          $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat_id);
          $cat_name = $category->getName();
          $cat_url =  $this->getBaseUrl().$category->getUrlPath();
       }

       if (is_array($this->_crumbs)) {
          reset($this->_crumbs);
          $this->_crumbs[key($this->_crumbs)]['first'] = true;
          end($this->_crumbs);
          $this->_crumbs[key($this->_crumbs)]['last'] = true;
       }

      foreach ($categoryIds as $cat_id) {
            if($cat_id) {
              $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat_id);
              $cat_name = $category->getName();
              //$cat_url =  $this->getBaseUrl().$category->getUrlPath();
              $cat_url =  $this->getBaseUrl().$connection->fetchOne("SELECT request_path from url_rewrite where entity_type = 'category' and entity_id = $cat_id");
              $this->_crumbs['category'.$cat_id] = array('label'=>$cat_name, 'title'=>'', 'link'=>$cat_url,'first'=>'','last'=>'','readonly'=>'');
              ksort($this->_crumbs);
           }
       }

       if($cat_id) {
         $home = $this->_crumbs['home'];
         unset($this->_crumbs['home']);
         array_unshift($this->_crumbs,$home);
       }
       $this->assign('crumbs', $this->_crumbs);

       return parent::_toHtml();

       //return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::_toHtml();
       //return $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686290/magento-calling-parent-function-not-working) for magento 1 but how can we write in magento 2 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This "return parent::_toHtml();" one will call parent breadcrumbs method and "return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template ::_toHtml();" will return template file's method.

Answer (score 0):

Create Module: {Vendor_Package}

create file {Vendor_Package}/frontend/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs">
    <arguments>
       <argument name="catalogData" xsi:type="object">{Vendor_Package}\Helper\Data</argument>
    </arguments>
 </type>
```

create helper file {Vendor_Package}\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor_Package}\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data
{
    /**
     * Return current category object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category|null
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        $category = parent::getCategory();

        if(!$category) {
         /**
          * Will be found the first the deepest category 
          **/
            $category = $this->getProduct()
                ->getCategoryCollection()
                ->setOrder('level','DESC')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', ['eq' => true])
                ->getFirstItem();
        }

        return $category;
    }
}
```